# Collection#find: pass a function instead

Tags: discord.js

I'm fairly new to node.js and I'm working on a discord bot with discord.js, I'm am trying to do assigned roles with commands. When I do the code and type in the command it works successfully but pops up with "DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead" in the console, how can I get rid of this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ca0N.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, markup, error messages, and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Please also say specifically what you're having trouble with (the error message seems fairly clear).

Answer (score 5):

This warning is caused by the following line:

`var role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'Epic Gamer');`

On an earlier version of Discord.js, this would be valid, but they have now redone the `find` function. Instead of taking in a property and a value, you pass in a filtering function instead. This should work:

`var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Epic Gamer")`

Instead of passing in `'name'` (the property), and `'Epic Gamer'` (the value we want to search for/filter out), we pass in the arrow function `role => role.name === 'Epic Gamer'`. This is like mapping. `find` passes every role from `message.guild.roles` into the function as `role`, and then checks if the property we want equals the value we want.

If you would like to learn more about the `find` function, please check out [the official documentation.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)

Answer (score 3):

Pass a predicate function in `find` method, take a look at the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) document on the `find` function.

Change the `find` statement to

```
var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Epic Gamer');
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: thank you i already did this now and the error is gone, But the problem still when i type 'role 1' and 'role 2' the bot gives me multiple roles instead of removing other roles. like the remove role code i wrote not working, any idea?