# (node:10124) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

Tags: discord.js

when i execute !x command it says

`(node:10124) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead`

`(node:10124) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead`

the issue is at `...let channe.. ..downchan...` as the console log says

`exports.startScrim = function(guild,host,type,time){
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x91bbff)
        .addField("message x","another message"+exports.one(time),false)
        .addField("Mode",type.toUpperCase(),true)
        .addField("Host",host,true)
        .addField("Instructions","message x",false)`

```
let channel = guild.channels.find("name",guilds[guild.id].digitchan);
let channel2 = guild.channels.find("name",guilds[guild.id].countdownchan);
if (channel && channel2) {
    channel.send(embed)`
```

and the next line `channel.send(embed)` is not even executing. help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of:
[Collection#find: pass a function instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247482/collectionfind-pass-a-function-instead)

Sounds like you need to do:

```
let channel = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === guilds[guild.id].digitchan);
let channel2 = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === guilds[guild.id].countdownchan);
```

Comment: thank you so much! but now there are no errors showing but still not executing the rest of the script

Comment: I would assume that either `channel` or `channel2` are not set. You're requiring that you find both of them before you move on to your next code. Are you sure that both of your `find`s are actually finding a channel?

Comment: Go for it! If you feel like this question is answered, you should click the check mark icon by my answer, to accept it as the answer to the question.

Comment: Well, in the meantime, try adding `console.log(channel)` and `console.log(channel2)` in and see if either of them are falsey.

Comment: Guild `asdasfasf` Members `4`
null      // these are the logs

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're printing. Is that `null` supposed to be `channel2`? Because if it is, then none of your code is going to run. You say `if (channel && channel2) {`, and so if `channel2` is `null`, then you're not getting inside that `if`.

Comment: I think you may want to break up your if into two of them, so that if you happen to find `channel` then do some things related to that, and if you happen to find `channel2`, do things related to that. Entirely independent of each other. But I have no idea what you're doing or if it makes sense to have a `digitchan` without a `countdownchan`.

Comment: is a scrim bot so i need both channels for the next lines (when the cooldown gets over i am gonna post the script) i set a voice `countdownchan` and  a chat `digitchan` channel to first play a countdown, and then hearing the scrims codes.